# How to Store NSDictionary values in an array in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:0];

appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"events"];
NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);

NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);
```

I want to store these two NSDictionary values in a single array

Comment: You need to save dicOne and dictTow in single array ?

Comment: please post your questions in proper format

Comment: ok i am posting in proper format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *dictArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[dictArray addObject:dictOne];
[dictArray addObject:dictTwo];
```

If you want to insert it at specific index..

```
[dictArray insertObject:dictOne atIndex:0];
[dictArray insertObject:dictTwo atIndex:1];
```

Refer to this link..
[NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

A shorter, but just as effective option is:

```
NSMutableArray *dictArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: dictOne, dictTwo, nil];
```

This code will initialize the array with dictOne in position 0 and dictTwo in position 1. The nil at the end is there to indicate to the objective-c compiler that this argument list is finished. if you try to request the item on position 2 you will get an error.

**PS:** If you don't intend to add or remove items from the array, you could also use NSArray.